# What is the mutual information between ingredients of a mixture of Gaussians?

Tags: normal-distribution, mutual-information

Consider 2 random variables, $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is discrete and $Y$ is continuous.

In particular, we have a Gaussian distribution $Y$  with mean $X$ and variance $\sigma = 1$, and

- $P(X=1) = \frac{1}{4}$,
- $P(X=2) = \frac{1}{4}$,
- $P(X=4) = \frac{1}{2}$

What is the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$? Is there an analytical solution to the problem? Otherwise, how to solve it numerically, given that the result is very sensitive to the binning choice?

[image]

Comment: Information in what sense? Actually if $Z\sim N(0,1)$ is independent of $X$ then $Y=X+Z.$

Comment: thanks for the comment, @GérardLetac. I agree that $Y=X+Z$.  I'm looking for the mutual information in information theory sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information

Comment: I tried to compute it  but we land on an integral  of the form $$\int_{R}\log (\sum_{x\in X}c_xe^{xy})e^{-y^2/2}dy$$ which is not explicitly computable.